# Laravel customize email verification

Tags: laravel

Im trying to customize the email verification email.
In the file  `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail.php`
I can see the following:

```
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject(Lang::get('Verify Email Address'))
        ->line(Lang::get('Please click the button below to verify your email address.'))
        ->action(Lang::get('Verify Email Address'), $verificationUrl)
        ->line(Lang::get('If you did not create an account, no further action is required.'));
}
```

The language of my application is nl and so far all my translations work.
I added a file messages.php to `\resources\lang\nl` with the following content:

```
<?php

return [
    'Verify Email Address' => 'Bevestig uw email adres',
];
```

However when the email is send the subject is not changed with the translation.
Where should I put the translation?

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327972/how-would-you-organize-mails-in-a-multilingual-laravel-application

Comment: @aimme that basicly says dont do it, but i dont see why not as im only supporting one language.

Comment: ya, just thought it might be helpful for you. so shared it with you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, I have to add a file `\resources\lang\nl\nl.json` and add the following:

```
{
    "Verify Email Address" : "Bevestig uw email adres"
}
```

Now it works as expected.